# How to skip words in a string until "DETAIL:" is found using C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this string:

```
USERNAME: ADMIN|00004|GI FILE: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet1.docx DETAIL:There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:5557/
```

I want to skip until **DETAIL:**, resulting on only:

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:5557/
```

How can I accomplish thus in C#?

Comment: Why LINQ specifically?

Comment: Because I'm learning linq at this moment.

Comment: There's no point using Linq here

Comment: Just to be extremely funny I'll point out that even though you may find a solution. You will never find the word DETAIL in your string ;)

Comment: Question updated. `using linq` removed. Other approaches accepted.

Comment: take a look  at my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use string operations instead of LINQ:

```
string substr = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("DETAIL:") + "DETAIL:".Length);
```

This code assumes that the string always contains `"DETAIL:"` as a substring. If it might not, then you should handle such cases. The least computationally-expensive way would be to check that `str.IndexOf("DETAIL:")` does not return `-1`.

```
string substr = null;
int pos = str.IndexOf("DETAIL:");
if (pos >= 0)
    substr = str.Substring(pos + "DETAIL:".Length);
else
    // Handle missing "DETAIL:"
```

**Edit**: If you absolutely want to use LINQ, you can treat strings as sequences of characters and use the following (inefficient) code:

```
string keyword = "DETAIL:"; 
int length = keyword.Length;
char[] chars = str.Select((c, i) => str.Skip(i))
                  .First(s => s.Take(length).SequenceEqual(keyword))
                  .Skip(length)
                  .ToArray();
string substr = new string(chars);
```

Comment: see the OP justification

Comment: Masterful. Some LINQ magic like that definitely belongs under [[code-trolling](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling)]

Answer (score 1):

For this, I'd prefer something like Douglas's answer. For the sake of completeness, this is also pretty suited to Regex:

```
var s = "USERNAME: ADMIN|00004|GI FILE: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet1.docx DETAIL:There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:5557/";
var pattern = @"(?<=DETAIL:).*";
var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(s, pattern);

foreach(var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}

// output: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:5557/
```

---

Regex Explanation:

- `(?<=DETAIL:)`

  - `(?<=[regex])` is a positive lookbehind, meaning that it looks to see that the next part of the regex has the regex after the `<=` behind it
  - `DETAIL:` just matches that exact string
- `.*` means "0 or more of any character"

  - `.` means "any character"
  - `*` means 0 or more of the previous item

---

If you *really* wanted to throw some LINQ in there, you can try using a multiline lambda with some temporary variables:

```
var temp = "";
var target = "DETAIL:";
var detail = String.Join("", s.SkipWhile(c => {
    if (temp == target) return false;               
    temp = target.Contains(c) ? temp + c : "";
    return true;
}));

Console.WriteLine(detail); // output: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:5557/
```

Since a `string` is technically an `IEnumerable<char>`, you can perform LINQ operations on them. The problem is that since LINQ will return you an `IEnumerable<char>`, you need to use somthing like `String.Join` or `new String(char[])` to put them back into a readable format. A temporary variable here is also used because LINQ operations will treat all characters individualy, so there is no real way to tell where we are in the string otherwise during execution.

Answer (score 0):

My simples solution:

```
var str1 = "USERNAME: ADMIN|00004|GI FILE: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet1.docx DETAIL:There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:5557/";

var keyword = "DETAIL:";
var str = str1.Split(new string[]{keyword}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are better ways but if you're hell bent on doing it in LINQ then something along the following lines:

```
string s = "USERNAME: ADMIN|00004|GI FILE: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet1.docx DETAIL:There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:5557/";
string r = string.Join(" ", s.Split(' ', ':').SkipWhile(x => x != "DETAIL").Skip(1));
Console.Write(r);
```

Should give you "There was no endpoint listening at http //localhost 5557/"

Note the lack of ":" because I needed to remove them in the Split(). It's not perfect but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Since a `string` is technically an `IEnumerable<char>`, I was trying to find some crafty way to do this without `Split` of `Join`, but I think this is about as close as w're going to get.

Answer (score 0):

OP goal => *`Because I'm learning linq at this moment`*
LINQ is based on [`extension method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)  to define standard query operators that add query functionality to the existing.

you can define something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s =
                @"USERNAME: ADMIN|00004|GI FILE: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet1.docx DETAIL:There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:5557/";
              var str =  s.SkipUntilWord("DETAIL:");
        }

    }
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static string SkipUntilWord(this String str,string word)
        {
            return str.Substring(str.IndexOf(word,StringComparison.CurrentCulture) + word.Length);
        }
    }
```